# Python - Convert tab delimited file into csv in a specific manner

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab delimited text file with each record having 10 columns as follows:

```
p001    64      20141209      meals (attendees)    ML   ENTER   Entertainment   xyz Restaurants      6.0     "_e' Restaurants (123) 456-7890 \r\n          FORUM \r\n     ,Around \r\n\r\n':33 113-2 \r\n\r\n 8440 XYZ09'15       1:11PM \r\n\r\n   1 Burger          6.00 \r\n\r\n    SSIONS      6.00 \r\n    TOTAL PAID    6 .00 \r\n    XXXXXXXXXXX2012 XX/XX \r\n    XYZ EXPRESS
6.00 \r\n\r\n\r\n  7,-10( YOU! FOR DINING WITH US! \r\n\r\n         113-2 \r\n\r\nYour r is: 840     \r\n"
```

P.S: The last column has text enclosed in "". And my 1st column is NOT unique.

I would like to convert this text file into a csv file such that I only pick the data from the 1st, 2nd, 8th, 9th and 10th columns of the record. In addition, all the data should be enclosed in "".

For example, the above record should be converted to the following line in the output csv file:

```
"p001","64","xyz Restaurants","6.0","_e' Restaurants (123) 456-7890 \r\n          FORUM \r\n     ,Around \r\n\r\n':33 113-2 \r\n\r\n 8440 XYZ09'15       1:11PM \r\n\r\n   1 Burger          6.00 \r\n\r\n    SSIONS      6.00 \r\n    TOTAL PAID    6 .00 \r\n    XXXXXXXXXXX2012 XX/XX \r\n    XYZ EXPRESS
    6.00 \r\n\r\n\r\n  7,-10( YOU! FOR DINING WITH US! \r\n\r\n         113-2 \r\n\r\nYour r is: 840     \r\n"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading and parsing a TSV file, then manipulating it for saving as CSV (\*efficiently\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992971/reading-and-parsing-a-tsv-file-then-manipulating-it-for-saving-as-csv-efficie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.  Note that this uses the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library for both input and output, we just change the text delimiter.  [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) should automatically escape your quote characters when you write the file.

```
import csv
try:
    with open(r'input.tsv', 'r', newline='\n') as in_f, \
         open(r'output.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as out_f:
        reader = csv.reader(in_f, delimiter='\t')
        writer = csv.writer(out_f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  # Quoting added per comment from @Rob.
        for li in reader:
            try:
                writer.writerow([li[0], li[1], li[2], li[7], li[8], li[9],])
            except IndexError:  # Prevent errors on blank lines.
                pass
except IOError as err:
    print(err)
```

I wasn't able to parse out where the tabs should be in your sample data (as opposed to spaces), but testing it with the following data for `input.tsv`:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

Will generate the following results in `output.csv`:

```
"1","2","3","8","9","10"
"11","12","13","18","19","20"
"21","22","23","28","29","30"
```

---

## Update

Note that the update in the code to add `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` was per a suggestion in the comments from Rob.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I think you missed the « *all the data should be enclosed in ""* ». Try `csv.writer(out_f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`.